# Form content in multiple languages: View behaviour and model handling

Tags: sapui5

Currently I work an an app where the user can create products for a catalog. The status is, he can do this in one language, data gets send to the backend and saved. The next step would be to make this creation process ready for multiple languages e.g. english or french. The behaviour should be the following, he choses the language inside a drop down field and gets a form in the selected language.

The problems I encountered and my solution process till now:

1) How should the view handling be? Should I create a new fragment for every language and exchange the content? If Im correct that would mean I would need to destroy and create fragements for the languages, right? And then create them with a binded model again.

2) How should I handle the model/models? Should I create one model with the data they share e.g. creation date and create a model with language related attributes? That would be my solution right now.

Maybe you already did something similiar or have some thoughts about this, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should do neither of those things. There are mechanisms in place, generally referred to as `i18n` that help you with this process. UI5 help available here:

https://ui5.sap.com/sdk#/topic/df86bfbeab0645e5b764ffa488ed57dc

and

https://ui5.sap.com/sdk#/topic/5424938fc60244c5b708d71b50a0eee4

In summary, translations should be done using the `i18n` mechanisms and the oData logon language.

Logging into the application, assuming it's hosted on an SAP gateway or SCP / Launchpad, the user's current logon language will drive at least all standard SAP translatable texts like the labels returned from data elements in your oData services. The appropriate url parameter is `sap-language=EN`, but it's set automatically from the current browser settings. Generally, you don't have to worry about this.

The same browser settings drive which particular i18n file is loaded. This could be specific like `en_US` for American English, or `fr` for French.

If you code your app without any hard coded translations but always follow the rules in the links above, adding a language should be trivial.

These translations could probably be triggered programmatically via a dropdown as well but I have never tried that since it's extra steps for my users.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I guess we are talking about two different subjects. For labels and all text related things in my controls I use the i18n models with their respective languages. What I'm talking about is the step where the user defines how this product is called in another language and how to build multiple forms for this to do it in the respective language.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I also fail to understand why the forms need to be in a different language for someone to provide a translation for a product. Is this something more intricate than the SE63 process? I'm not sure I get your requirement

Comment: The reason for this is more a user experience thing. Maybe this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iutVw.png) from this [thread](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/96097/ux-ui-responsive-long-forms-with-multiple-language-content) explains what I want to achieve better than my words could ever do :)

Comment: Well, if you turn the entity into an entityset of languages the content in the link can be an icon tab bar which you can actually do dynamically